# Wrong value when converting Celsius/Fahrenheit

Tags: android, android-activity

This is a basic unit conversion application.

I just have finished coding and everything works fine except the Fahrenheit and Celsius calculation. The formula is right, but don't know why.

Here is `Activity.Java`

```
package arirang.unit.converter;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class BasicUnitConverterActivity extends Activity {

    EditText val3;
    String val2;
    int val1;
    String forResult;
    Spinner Type;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.UnitList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    private String changeFormat(Double dbResult) {
        String result;

        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
        result = format.format(dbResult);
        return result;
    }



    public void converter(View View) {


        EditText val3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.BeforeBox);
        String val2 = val3.getText().toString();
        if (val2.length() > 0) {

            val1 = Integer.parseInt(val2);
            Type = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);

            double dbResult = 0;

            if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("meter to inch")) {
                dbResult = val1 * 39.3700787;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("meter to feet")) {
                dbResult = val1 * 3.2808399;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("feet to inch")) {
                dbResult = val1 * 12;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("feet to meter")) {
                dbResult = val1 / 3.2808399;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("inch to meter")) {
                dbResult = val1 / 39.3700787;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("inch to feet")) {
                dbResult = val1 / 12;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("kilogram to pound")) {
                dbResult = val1 * 2.20462262;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("pound to kilogram")) {
                dbResult = val1 / 2.20462262;
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Fahrenheit to Celsius")) {
                dbResult = (val1 - 32) * (5 / 9);
            } else if (Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Celsius to Fahrenheit")) {
                dbResult = (val1 * (9 / 5)) + 32;
            }

            forResult = changeFormat(dbResult);

            TextView AfterBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AfterBox);
            AfterBox.setText(forResult);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

`dbResult=(val1 - 32) * (5 / 9);` should be `dbResult=(val1 - 32) * (5f / 9);` The issue is that when you write 5/9 this means that you are dividing int values and hence the result will be 0( 5 is less than 9 so 5/9 is 0. Had it been 10/9 the result would have been 1). By adding a cast to float to one of the arguments the compiler does what is called a widening-primitive-type-conversion and promotes both of the arguments of the / operator to float. Now that the division is done between float values the result will be the one you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely make "val1" a float, and do all my math in "double" space.  Truncate or round to integer when you're done - not while you're calculating.

```
  double val1;
  ...
  dbResult = (val1 * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32.0;
  ...
```

IMHO...